# How to execute a java program without main method in java 1.7 . I know it works in other releases but i want in 1.7

Tags: java, program-entry-point

As far as my knowledge without main core java execution that to in java 1.7 is impossible but still if any answer is there means I am looking for the answer. I don't want the class javafx.application to be appended in the program and all I know is we need to use the thread to get the answer

Comment: It does not work in other releases.

Comment: What wrong has **pubic static void main(String[] args)** done to you?

Comment: No  you can't run a java application without main of javax.appliation.

Comment: To run a standalone application, your program execution will from `main()` irrespective of any JAVA version.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please read it to yourself, bearing in mind that we don't have *any* context other than what you supply. Then edit it to give us all the information we need to help you.

Comment: How to execute a Java program without a main - well I guess you build a native application, use the JNI invocation API and bootstrap the JVM that way. But since the question is so unclear, I have no idea if that is part of the game rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, though I don't see how this helps you at all.

```
public class Main {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

You can "run" this class without a main method.

EDIT: This works on Java 7 update 59 and Java 8 update 51.

```
$ /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -cp . Main
Hello World

$ /opt/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java -cp . Main
Hello World
```

Comment: Hello peter is there any way other than this. I mean i saw the same program floating every where. The answer i want is not static block but through threads. But anyways thanks for your answer. I am happy

Comment: @AnupDRao You could hack the Thread or Reflection class in theory, but there is no other simple way to do this.

Comment: @AnupDRao you could hack the method which prints that there is no main() so that it actually runs your program instead.

Comment: ok thanks again for the response. could you please tell me how to hack the thread(in theory means)

Comment: @AnupDRao Take a copy of the Thread class in src.zip. Edit it. Compile it and prepend it to your -X:bootclasspath/p={dir}